# How do I configure lint to pick up formatting errors?

Tags: angular, formatting, lint, angular14

I'm using Angular 14 and the same version of angular-eslint/eslint-plugin.  I have intentionally introduced these formatting errors in my component

```
Welcome {{name }}
```

and its service (no indentation) ...

```
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.subject.next();
  this.subject.complete();
  }
```

However, when I run "ng lint", these errors are not reported.  Is this not something that "ng lint" reports or is there some other configuration I need to enable for it to pick it up?

Comment: There's not enough information here, what's your CLI builder?

Comment: Not quite understanding, what do you mean CLI builder?  I have "@angular/cli": "~14.1.3" defined in my package.json if that's what you mean.

Comment: What does your angular.json looks like? There should be a lint property there.

Comment: please provide your eslintrc.json. There are the rules defined.